# What happens to my classes in my "shared project" when app is breaked on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I have been trying to imlement in my app a way to run some task when app is **"closed"** or **"breaked"**, I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` to do this, but I have notice something that could be logical. In my Broadcast receiver I am using classes from my shared project or PCL, but when app is breaked I have noticed that the only class that still exists is the BroadcastReceiver one, so when I do call a class that is in my shared project in my broadcast it gives me an error, I have conclude this beacuse when my app hasn't been breaked the execution to call the classes of the shared project is OK, but when breaked... not,
I have two questions for this problem:
1) Is my theory correct?
2) If is correct (or not) how can I call from my BroadcastReceiver classes that are in my shared project when the app is **breaked**?

Here is some sample of my code:

```
//Android

override void OnReceive(...)//BroadcastReceiver main method
{
     ...
     MyClass myCls = new MyClass();//Class from shared project
}
```

When I execute this when app is still in use everything of but when is breaker then the app stops and shows me the following typical android pop up:

```
“MyAplication.Drioid has stopped”
```

Comment: Adding the relevant portions of your code (or even a [mcve]) could help understanding your issue. I am having a really hard time understanding what the actual issue is.

Comment: @PaulKertscher just recently edited, can you check mi new post?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to let your app restart again after the app is `closed`? If yes,for android, you can try to use `service`  to achieve this.

When the service is in the background, you can try to restart it by using a BroadcastReceiver which will receive a signal when someone or something kills the service, its role is to restart the service.

For more details, you can refer to: https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

**Note**:Even though it's Java code, it's easy to understand and convert.

For xamarin Form, because each platform has their own way and rules for background services. You have to make services for each platform.

You can refer to this document: [Xamarin Background Tasks](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/)